# iPhone app or mod in cydia to remap headset inline remote buttons?

Tags: iphone, headphones, cydia, package-management

I was wondering if there's any package in Cydia or iPhone app that would allow me to change the inline remote buttons behavior. I often walk around the cydia with my headphones on and speaking the VoiceOver commands is really unconfortable.

I can normally reach my iphone from my pocket to switch up or down the volume, so I would like to use the headset buttons to skip songs.

Comment: Double clicking the center button will skip to the next song in the iPod app normally, I don't know if jailbreaking would affect that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone needs this too I've found that the package [External iPod controls](http://www.funkyspacemonkey.com/external-ipod-controls-convert-volume-buttons-ipod-controls) ($0.99), lets me remap my iPhone external volume buttons to change songs, so I can skip to the next song pressing the volume buttons when my iPhone is in my pocket, and I can still control the volume levels from my headset buttons.

Answer (score 0):

activator in cydia is what you are looking for.  Complete button remapping/shortcut creator.